# How can I re-sort a sorted array by absolute values, in linear time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

You are given a sorted array containing both negative and positive values. Resort the array taking absolute value of negative numbers. Your complexity should be O(n)

**Sample Input**

```
[-8, -5, -3, -1, 3, 6, 9]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[ -1, -3, 3, -5, 6, -8, 9 ]
```

I have done this till now, but output is not correct.

```
function sortMe(input) {
   var newArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
     var value = Math.abs(input[i]);
     newArr.push(value);
   }
   var c = newArr.sort()
}
```

and it is giving output

```
[ 1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Split the array in to two halves, one with negative numbers and the other with positive numbers.
2. Reverse the negative numbers array.
3. Then, run [merging algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) with the absolute value of both the arrays.

Overall runtime complexity is still O(n).

---

```
function sortMe(sortedArray) {

  var idx = -1, negs, pos, result = [], nIdx = 0, pIdx = 0;

  if (sortedArray.length === 0)
    return result;

  // Find the index where positive elements begin
  while (idx < sortedArray.length && sortedArray[++idx] < 0);

  // Get elements till the index and reverse the array
  negs = sortedArray.slice(0, idx).reverse();

  // Get elements from the index till the end
  pos = sortedArray.slice(idx);

  // Merging algorithm implementation which merges `negs` and `pos`
  while (nIdx < negs.length || pIdx < pos.length)
  {
    if (nIdx < negs.length && pIdx < pos.length)
    {
      if (Math.abs(negs[nIdx]) <= pos[pIdx])
        result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
      else
        result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
    }
    else if (nIdx < negs.length)
      result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
    else
      result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(sortMe([-8, -5, -3, -1, 3, 6, 9]));
// [ -1, -3, 3, -5, 6, -8, 9 ]
```

```js
function sortMe(sortedArray) {

  var idx = -1, negs, pos, result = [], nIdx = 0, pIdx = 0;

  if (sortedArray.length === 0)
    return result;

  // Find the index where positive elements begin
  while (idx < sortedArray.length && sortedArray[++idx] < 0);

  // Get elements till the index and reverse the array
  negs = sortedArray.slice(0, idx).reverse();

  // Get elements from the index till the end
  pos = sortedArray.slice(idx);

  // Merging algorithm implementation which merges `negs` and `pos`
  while (nIdx < negs.length || pIdx < pos.length)
  {
    if (nIdx < negs.length && pIdx < pos.length)
    {
      if (Math.abs(negs[nIdx]) <= pos[pIdx])
        result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
      else
        result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
    }
    else if (nIdx < negs.length)
      result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
    else
      result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
  }

  return result;
}

function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function sorter() {
  var data = getElement("numbers").value.split(" ").map(Number);
  getElement("result").innerHTML = "[" + sortMe(data).join(", ") + "]";
}
```

```html
<input id="numbers" value="-8 -5 -3 -1 3 6 9" />
<input type="button" onclick="sorter()" value="Click here to Sort" />
<pre id="result" />
```

Comment: The code has a bug in the line: while (idx < sortedArray.length && sortedArray[++idx] < 0);
It should be: while (++idx < sortedArray.length && sortedArray[idx] < 0);

Answer (score 1):

Can be done by taking in mind 3 cases:

a. All positive numbers : leave the array as is

b. All negative numbers : reverse the array

c. Positive as well as negative numbers : find last negative number in input array and then use left and right to compare.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortAbsoluteValue {
    // all positive; all negative; postive & negative
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num = new int[] { -8, -5, -3, -1, 3, 6, 9 };
        int[] result = sortAbsolute(num);

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(result[i]);
        }
    }

    private static int[] sortAbsolute(int[] num) {
        int size = num.length;
        // all positive : leave as is
        if (num[0] >= 0)
            return num;
        // all negative : reverse array
        if (num[size-1] < 0) {
            int[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(num, num.length);
            Arrays.sort(temp);
            return temp;
        }
        int[] result = new int[size];

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            if (num[i] < 0 && num[i + 1] >= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        int left = i - 1;
        int right = i + 1;
        result[0] = num[i];
        int k = 0;
        while (left >= 0 && right < size) {
            if (Math.abs(num[left]) < num[right]) {
                result[++k] = num[left];
                left--;
            } else {
                result[++k] = num[right];
                right++;
            }
        }
        // remaining left elements, if any
        while(left>=0) {
            result[++k] = num[left--];
        }
        // remaining right elements, if any
        while(right<size) {
            result[++k] = num[right++];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@thefourtheye, your solution is very good, but it does not correct process number sequences where numbers(positive and negative ones) are mixed.
You can check your solution with the next sequence, for example:
[-2 -5 3 8 -10]
and it will give you wrong result : [3, -5, -2, 8, -10].

This is because:

1) You rely that negative and positive numbers should go in the sorted order.

2) Find indexes of positive and negative numbers despite the fact that they can go inconsistently.

I've corrected your code and now it can process any mixed positive/negative number sequences and correctly sort them by absolute values. Code is below:

```
function sortArrayByAbsValues(sortedArray) {

                var negs = [], pos = [], result = [], nIdx = 0, pIdx = 0;

                if (sortedArray.length === 0)
                    return result;

                //prepare negative/positive number sequences.
                for (var i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
                    var value = sortedArray[i];
                    if (value < 0) {
                        negs.push(value);
                    } else {
                        pos.push(value);
                    }
                }
                // sort positive/negative numbers
                pos = pos.sort();
                negs = negs.sort();

                // Merging algorithm implementation which merges `negs` and `pos`
                while (nIdx < negs.length || pIdx < pos.length) {
                    if (nIdx < negs.length && pIdx < pos.length) {
                        if (Math.abs(negs[nIdx]) <= pos[pIdx])
                            result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
                        else
                            result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
                    }
                    else if (nIdx < negs.length)
                        result.push(negs[nIdx++]);
                    else
                        result.push(pos[pIdx++]);
                }

                return result;
            }
```

Comment: That wasn't the question. The initial array is sorted. Why would the numbers be mixed? All negative numbers would be consecutive and then all positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this using Bubble sort

```
 var array= new Array(2,-2,3,5,-3,1);

 function absoluteSortin(array){

    var inputArray= array.slice(0);
    var temp;

    for(var i=0;i< inputArray.length;i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<inputArray.length;j++){
            if(Math.abs(inputArray[i]) > Math.abs(inputArray[j])){
                temp= inputArray[j];
                inputArray[j] = inputArray[i];
                inputArray[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
   return inputArray;

 }
 absoluteSortin(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array(-2,-3,0,5,4,1,6,9,7,-9,-1,3);
for($i=0;$i<count($a)-1;$i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<count($a)-1;$j++){
        $data1=abs($a[$j]);
        $data2=abs($a[$j+1]);
        if($data1>$data2) {
            $temp = $a[$j];
            $a[$j] = $a[$j+1];
            $a[$j+1] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_R($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
int[] arr = new int[] { -8, -5, -3, -1, 3, 6, 9 };
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int pos = 0;                
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (Math.abs(arr[pos]) > Math.abs(arr[j])) {
            int temp;
            temp = arr[pos];
            arr[pos] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            pos++;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your complexity should be O(n). You have O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Python

```
    def sorted_array(list1):
        list_negative=[]
        list_positive=[]

        for i in list1:
        if i<0:
            list_negative.append(i)
        else:
            list_positive.append(i)

        list_negative.reverse()    

        for i in list_negative:
            for j in range(0, len(list_positive)):
                if abs(i)<=list_positive[j]:
                    list_positive.insert(j,i)
                    break
        print(list_positive)    
    list1=[-8,-5,-3,-1,3,6,9,-4]    
    sorted_array(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

two pointer approach.

```
void resort(vector<int> &a){

   int par ; // partition index (when +ve elements starts)

   // lets find where positive elements starts
   for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
      if(a[i] >= 0) {
         par = i;
         break;
      }
   }

  int l = par-1; // left of par
  int r = par;   // right side

  vector<int> b; // extra array for answer

 
  // compare left and right side element
  // if any of them is lesser push that element in extra array i.e 'b'
  while(l >= 0 and r < a.size()) {

     if(abs(a[l]) > a[r]) {
        b.push_back(a[r]);
        r++;
     }
     else if(abs(a[l]) < a[r]){
        b.push_back(a[l]);
        l--;
     }
     else{
        b.push_back(a[l]);
        l--;
     }
  }

 // push remaing element from both side
 // like merge sort

  while(l >= 0) {
    b.push_back(a[l]);
    l--;
  }
  while(r < a.size()) {
     b.push_back(a[r]);
     r++;
  }

  // print modified answer
  for(auto x:b) {
     cout<<x<<" ";
  }
}
```

Time Compl. O(N)

Space Compl. O(N)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with one line in Python

```
nums = [-8, -5, -3, -1, 3, 6, 9]

print(sorted(nums,key=abs))
```

The output will be

```
[-1, -3, 3, -5, 6, -8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick solution

- break list in two part first part negative and second list will contains positive number
- apply merge algorithm to merge both list
  example in c#-.

  ```
  List<int> neg = arr.Where(x => x < 0).Reverse().ToList();
  List<int> pos = arr.Where(x => x > 0).ToList();
  var res=merge(neg,pos);    

   private static List<int> merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            while (left.Count > 0 || right.Count > 0)
            {
                if (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(left.First()) <= right.First())  
                    {
                        result.Add(left.First());
                        left.Remove(left.First());     
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(right.First());
                        right.Remove(right.First());
                    }
                }
                else if (left.Count > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(left.First());
                    left.Remove(left.First());
                }
                else if (right.Count > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(right.First());

                    right.Remove(right.First());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
inputArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return Math.abs(a) - Math.abs(b);
});
```

Might not be O(n) but worked well for me

Comment: Your complexity should be O(n). sort function uses a sorting algorithm with O(n * log(n)) time complexity.